# How to fix a trouble when pip throws ConnectionError?

Tags: pip

I have pip v 22.2
I try to upgrade a django package from 4.0.4 to 4.0.6
After calling

```
pip install --upgrade django
```

I have got:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f498f265d60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /packages/12/97/e341b13d605a9d0732a37975ce6bfae643c296721b8644f42d5d720c99bf/Django-4.0.6-py3-none-any.whl

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/12/97/e341b13d605a9d0732a37975ce6bfae643c296721b8644f42d5d720c99bf/Django-4.0.6-py3-none-any.whl (Caused by NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f498f28b7c0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution'))
```

What should I do to fix it? It normally worked a day ago.
It works good when I use mobile traffic, but not works in home network.